# Wrong value from a form in a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, view, controller, null

This a dumb question but even after some research i can't fix this problem.
I have a form in one of my view that allow me to get a value from a visitor.
I'm trying to get that value submitted in the form in my controller. And I don't understand
why but it seems that the only value that I get with this code is 0..
I think I don't use the correct synthax.
Here is my code from the view :

```
.mybox
            %p Tentative de vote.
            = @useful_tool.nbofrate
            = @useful_tool.nbtotal
            = @useful_tool.newrate
            = form_for(@useful_tool) do |f|
              = f.select :newrate, [['1 étoile', 1],['2 étoiles', 2],['3 étoiles', 3],['4 étoiles', 4],['5 étoiles', 5]]
              = f.submit
```

Here is my code from my controller :

```
  def update
    @useful_tool = UsefulTool.find_by_slug!(params[:id])
    @useful_tool.nbofrate = @useful_tool.nbofrate + 1
    value = params[:newrate]
    @useful_tool.nbtotal += value.to_i
    @useful_tool.rating = @useful_tool.nbtotal / @useful_tool.nbofrate
    update! { url_for(action: "index") }
  end
```

Because apparantly value must be nil I don't understand why.
Any help would be very apreciate. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to use `to_s.to_d` with nbtotal and value.

or you can explicitly check for nil

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
But i get : "undefined method `to_d' for "":String". Proof that the value that I get is nil. Check for nil won't work since the controller in called when I submit my form that contains only 1 data : this value. So it can't be nil, I need it. There must be an error in the way I try to get the value ...

Comment: Actually there are different typecasts that you can set such as Array: to_a

Float: to_f

Integer: to_i

String: to_s

Comment: Thanks, actually the typecasts "to_s" works. I don't get any error but the value that I get is 0. So my issue isn't fix yet ^^"... I don't know why I don't get the good value when my form is submit. I should get 1, 2,3,4 or 5 nothing else ...

Comment: So I figured out where my mistake was :

    value = params[:newrate]
has to be :

    value = params[:useful_tool][:newrate].to_i
otherwise the controller can't find the "newrate" data. And the ".to_i" is use to cast the string into an integer as it was said in a previous answer. Thanks every one.

Hope it could help someone else.

Comment: If you find any post helpful.. please encourage by giving a valuable vote :)..I am glad that this post was helpful to you..

Comment: I would like to encourage this but i can't give vote yet :/ .... I don't have enought reputation :/ (it needs 15points and I'm very new on this forum sry)